# How to run the application at windows startup without touch the Registry?

Tags: c++, windows, registry

In my Windows 7, some applications run automatically at startup but in in the Run key of the registry there is nothing about these applications.
So I would to know How to run the application at windows startup without touch the Registry.

Comment: You can put a shortcut in the Startup folder of the Start menu.

Comment: This question belongs at superuser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a non-exhaustive list of ways on might run something at startup:

- HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
- HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run (for 64bit Windows)
- HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
- Install a service
- Schedule a task (seems quite trendy... Google Updater does this, look here: `%SystemRoot%\system32\taskschd.msc /s`)
- Startup folder

Answer (score 1):

you can put a shortcut of the application in 
%userprofile%\Start Menu\Programs\startup
folder

Answer (score 1):

There is "Startup" section in Start->All Programs->Startup. You can put any batch script or exe.

Answer (score 1):

Download the Microsoft (formerly SysInternals) utility AUTORUNS (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902).  This will give you an overview of every place where an application can 'register' itself for automatic startup.